# JavaSwing How to bind label visibility to a jToggleButton and a jSpinner

Tags: java, swing, bind

I have 10 labels with an icon on each one of them. Then there is 1 jToggleButton and 1 jSpinner. The Spinner goes from 1 to 10, and the ToggleButton is to determine whether the labels are visible or not. Imagine this, I want to put label 3 visible. I go to the Spinner and choose 3, then click the ToggleButton to make it go visible. 
How can I do that? 
I've been checking out the bind option, but it's a bit complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Often times the best way for you to do this, and also the best way for you to complete your project is to try to "divide and conquer", to break your big problem into its small constituent steps, and then try to solve each small step one at a time. If a step is especially difficult, then try to subdivide it, and try to solve it in isolation from your big program. So here your steps can include:

1. Creating an ArrayList or array of JLabels
2. Add listeners to your JToggleButton and your JSpinner
3. When the listeners are activated, check the state of the toggle button and the spinner
4. Get the appropriate label set its visibility accordingly.

Note, I wouldn't go the "binding" route as this is more for database binding and such.

Since this homework, the code should be your responsibility.